# Responsive - spacing of 2 columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem, i want to make two columns and have responsive effect. 
left columns have 2 parts, top is text, image below it. right part is image. But it has a big spacing between 2 columns.if set padding or margin, when responsive will not float left. Thank you so much.

[image: The grid like this, with responsive]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { margin: 0; }

.columnsContainer { position: relative; margin: .5em; }

.leftColumn, .rightColumn{  border: 1px solid  #ccc; padding: 1.25em; }

.leftColumn { margin-bottom: .5em; }



/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em ) {
  .leftColumn { margin-right: 19.5em; }

 .rightColumn { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 18.75em; }   
}



.leftColumn img{
     margin-top: 27px;
} 
.leftColumn {
        float: left;
     width: 67%;
    }
    .rightColumn {
  float: left;
     width: 37%;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .group:after {
        content:"";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .leftColumn, .rightColumn {
            float: none;

   .navigation  {
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:0;

}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="leftColumn">
                <p> Fire safety is a principal concern for naval engineers. On-board fires often escalate quickly, causing massive damage to equipment, facilities and the environment. More importantly, they typically occur in remote areas where assistance is limited and serious injuries or loss of life unfortunately result. Vessel and offshore fires usually start in engine rooms, machinery, electrical controls and storage rooms. </p>
                <img src="img/marine/photo_1.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="rightColumn">
                <img src="img/marine/photo_2.jpg" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you set leftColumn have `width 67%` and right column have `width 37%`. It cannot fit the container. Just change the width.

```css
    @charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.columnsContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin: .5em;
}

.leftColumn,
.rightColumn {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1.25em;
}

.leftColumn {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}

.rightColumn {
  float: right width: 30%;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em) {
  .leftColumn {
    margin-right: 19.5em;
  }
  .rightColumn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 18.75em;
  }
}

.leftColumn img {
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.leftColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}

.rightColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .leftColumn,
  .rightColumn {
    float: none;
    .navigation {
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="leftColumn">
        <p> Fire safety is a principal concern for naval engineers. On-board fires often escalate quickly, causing massive damage to equipment, facilities and the environment. More importantly, they typically occur in remote areas where assistance is limited
          and serious injuries or loss of life unfortunately result. Vessel and offshore fires usually start in engine rooms, machinery, electrical controls and storage rooms. </p>
        <img src="img/marine/photo_1.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="rightColumn">
        <img src="img/marine/photo_2.jpg" />
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```